# IS4 MVC with multiple APIs communication problem

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I'm refactoring a monolithic ASP.NET Core MVC application. What I have so far is I added IS4 and extracted part of logic from MVC to new API.

This is how I set up IS4:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() =>
    new List<ApiScope> 
    {
        new ApiScope("CRMApi", "CRM API Scopes"),                
    };

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() =>
    new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("CRMApi", "CRM API Resources")
        {
            Scopes = { "CRMApi" },
            Enabled = true,
            UserClaims = { "sub", "name", "email" },
        },
    };

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
    new List<Client>
    {
       new Client
       {
           ClientId = "CRMClientMVC",
           ClientName = "MVC Client",
           ClientSecrets = { new Secret("MVCSecret".Sha512()) },
           AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
           RequirePkce = false,
           AllowedScopes = {
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
               "CRMApi",
           },
           RedirectUris = new List<string>{ $"{Discovery.CRMClient}/signin-oidc" },
           PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { $"{Discovery.CRMClient}/signout-callback-oidc" }
       },
       new Client
        {
            ClientId = "CRMNewApi",
            ClientName = "CRM API",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("CRMApi.secret".Sha256()) },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
            RequirePkce = false,
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                "CRMApi",
            },                    
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
        },
    };
```

My MVC code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";                
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opt =>
{
    opt.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    opt.Authority = discoverySettings.IdentityApi;
    opt.ClientId = "CRMClientMVC";
    opt.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    opt.SaveTokens = true;
    opt.ClientSecret = "MVCSecret";
    opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    opt.Scope.Add("email");
    opt.Scope.Add("CRMApi");
});
```

and API code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", opt =>
{
    opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    opt.Authority = discoverySettings.IdentityApi;
    opt.Audience = "CRMApi";
});
```

I am able to register new users and to login. When I go to any subpage I'm able to call the API from the MVC code which is great.

**PROBLEM**

But because the dependencies between MVC and API are significant, I have to also call MVC from API.

And this is where I have problems. When I call MVC from API I get status code 200, but the response content is IS4 login page html ?!

```
<head>
    ...
    <title>IdentityServer4</title>    
    ...
</head>
...
```

And this is what I see in the console:

MVC console:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
2023-03-14 11:16:08.9242|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService|Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

IS console:

```
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing login: User is not authenticated
```

The flow is usually like this:

1. I click something in the front page
2. This executes some action in MVC with `[Authorize]` attribute
3. MVC calls API
4. This executes some action in API with `[Authorize]` attribute
5. But the API requires some data from MVC to finish it's job, so it calls MVC
6. This executes yet another action in MVC with `[Authorize]` attribute
   but that doesn't work as described

This is how I make my calls from API. I copy the MVC access token into the request

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClientType.ToString());
 
var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
var authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = authorization;
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

I removed the access token from request but result was the same.

I tried to add MVC resource and scope and then include it in the API scopes but this doesn't work. Probably because the way I make my API->MVC call.

```
new ApiResource("CRMClient", "CRM Client MVC Resources")
{
    Scopes = { "CRMClient" },
    Enabled = true,
    UserClaims = { "sub", "name", "email" },
}
```

```
new ApiScope("CRMClient", "CRM Client MVC Scopes")
```

And in the API client I added this scope

```
"CRMClient"
```

Result was still the same.

**QUESTION**

I'm wondering what am I missing here? Should I somehow authorize my API on startup? Store the token somewhere and send that token in the request message to MVC? I'm totally clueless here.

What if I add second, third API and want all the APIs and MVC to be able to communicate with each other?

I can share more details e.g. token if needed.

Thank you in advance.

**[EDIT]**

MVC Pipeline

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

API Pipeline

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**[EDIT 2]**

Headers
Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2023 19:14:18 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.czJr-f0sbFI=CfDJ8Hte0q9brmpGhdFRy07dtGFOwpjKL_7dq88vMoxDcyKMtx_CXPM8GJ577R7CSWmwy0juTRiI0Gxx5-eWfgi94JdsCK1bzcbA76spBFnK-tUPqm3qiE0ZwaHD2REm23Rg39En7KuLKddasSbUin7Zw; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self';
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self';
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

Comment: To get a more sanity in a given IdentityServer setup, I usually recommend to put the IS, client and API in separate services, otherwise you will have a hard time troubleshooting what is what and when it does not work.

Comment: Also, can be good to add the app.UseXXXX(); statements (your request pipeline part)

Comment: @ToreNestenius I added MVC and API pipelines. MVC, IS and API are separate services.

Comment: How do you call the API from the client? Also ,see my answer and let me know what the result is from the header.

Comment: I added header attributes in the EDIT section of the question

Comment: Sorry I forgot to metion these headers are response headers

Comment: Your API calls the MVC client as well? Bit confused about the flow, you didn't include IdenttiyServer in your flow description. ?

Comment: Yes my API calls MVC in the end as in the flow description I provided. If there are any calls to IS these have to be background calls which I don't control.

Comment: Are you sure you call the correct endpoint when you call the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem was setting Identity cookies. No changes to IS or MVC or API settings were required.

Here is how I did that:

When I call API from MVC I set both token and cookies. Token is required for the request to get authorized by the API. Why? Because JWT token i used for authorization and it's in the API configuration! DUH!

When I call MVC from API i use cookies sent in previous request to get authorized by MVC. Why? Because cookies are used for autorization and its in the MVC configuration! DUH!

This the code I use to copy cooies from MVC->API request to API->MVC request

```
if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Cookie", out var cookies))
{
    requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", cookies as IEnumerable<string>);
}
```

Code to set authorization token is presented in the question.

Thank you @ToreNestenius for your help. When you asked about cookies I relized I'm such a dork!

Answer (score 0):

In general it looks good when I first look at it.

One thing you can do is to enable error details by:

```
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    ...
}
```

Enabling this flag will result in that a more detailed error message in the WWW-Authenticate header, as shown below:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

You can find more ideas on how to troublehshoot API problems from a blog post that I recently wrote:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thank you Tore for Advice. Problem is that I don't get 401 error. I get 200 and the response content is IS login page HTML. I added that option you mentioned but since it's 200 response API logs show nothing interesting.

Comment: You get a 200 to the API? that could be that the request does not contain any cookie? Is your controller hit if you put a breakpoint in it? if you can hit your breakpoint, what does the User object contain? I would create an endpoint in the API that does not require authorization and just put a breakpoint inside it and explore what the Usre object contains.

Comment: I would use a tool like Fiddler to explore your Request traffic as well. (https://www.getfiddler.com/ )